# Example 2.10.3 from Artin

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am self-studying abstract algebra using MIT's publicly available materials.  The textbook for the class is Michael Artin's Algebra, 2nd edition.  (Not surprising, as the professor for the course is Artin as well.)  In the section on the Correspondence Theorem, he uses the example of the sign homomorphism $\sigma:S_n \to \lbrace \pm 1\rbrace$, stating that if $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ such that $|H|$ is odd, then $H$ is necessarily in the kernel of $\sigma$, i.e. $H$ is a subgroup of the alternating group $A_n$.

Why?  I understand that the index of $H$ in $S_n$ will be even; in an unrelated bit of flailing around, I know that $A_n$ is generated by three-cycles for $n \geq 3$, but I suspect that neither of these facts is helpful for grasping Artin's assertion.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the text immediately above. I am following Artin's Algebra, page 62.

You may restrict the sign isomorphism to your subgroup $H$, then the Counting formula says that the order of the image, i.e. $\sigma(H)$ divides both the order of your subgroup, an odd number, as well as the order of the image.

Suppose, the elements of subgroup $H$ are both odd and even permutations, so map surjectively onto -1 and +1. The order of the image would be 2, and 2 would have to divide the order of your subgroup $H$, which is an odd number by assumption. A contradiction.

So the order of the image is 1, and the whole subgroup must map into either -1 or +1. A group homomorphism must map an identity into an identity, so the only possibility is that $H$ maps into 1.

The kernel of a sign homomorphism for a permutation group is the Alternating group, definition on page 49.

Therefore $H$ is in the kernel, i.e. in the Alternating group. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have $H/(H\cap A_n)\cong HA_n/A_n\leq S_n/A_n$, so $[H:H\cap A_n]$ is a divisor of $2=[S_n:A_n]$. But, as $|H|$ is odd, so is $[H:H\cap A_n]$. This shows that $H\cap A_n=H$, or $H\leq A_n$.

**EDIT:** Here is a proof avoiding quotient groups (and using your version of the correspondence theorem). Recall that if $H,K$ are two subgroups of a finite group $G$, then 
$$|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|.$$
Moreover, if $K$ is normal in $G$, then $HK$ is a subgroup.

Now, consider $HA_n\subset S_n$ containing $A_n$. By the correspondence theorem, this corresponds to a subgroup $H'\subset\{\pm1\}$, and
$$|HA_n|=|H'||A_n|.$$
Using the formula above, we deduce that $|H|/|H\cap A_n|=|H'|$. Since the left-hand side is odd, and $|H'|\leq 2$, we must have $|H'|=1$. That is, $|H\cap A_n|=|H|$.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using techniques I haven't yet learned; I'm certainly unfamiliar with your notation.  What does $H/(H \cap A_n)$ mean?  $HA_n/A_n$?  $S_n/A_n$?

Comment: $H\cap A_n$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $H/(H\cap A_n)$ is the quotient group. Since $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, the product $HA_n=\{xy\in S_n\mid x\in H, y\in A_n\}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. It contains $A_n$, and $HA_n/A_n$ is the quotient. How is it that you are studying the correspondence theorem without being familiar with quotient groups?

Comment: You'd have to ask Artin.  The correspondence theorem is section 2.10 in his book, while quotient groups are section 2.12

Comment: Please state the correspondence theorem as you are learning it. The version I know: "There is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of subgroups of $G/N$ and the set of subgroups of $G$ containing $N$."

Comment: Let $\varphi:G \to G'$ be a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $K$.  There is a bijective correspondence between subgroups of $G'$ and subgroups of $G$ that contain $K$.  If $H$  and $H'$ are corresponding subgroups, then $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $H'$ is normal in $G'$.  Moreover, if $H$ and $H'$ are corresponding subgroups, $|H| = |H'||K|$.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that this statement lies several paragraphs ahead of where my perplexing example occurs.  Said example is merely (supposed to be) illustrating the concept of restricting a homomorphism.