# Artin's Example 2.10.3

Tags: abstract-algebra

In example 2.10.3, if H is a subgroup (odd order) of a Symmetric group, then H is contained in the kernel i.e H is a subgroup of Alternating group. But Artin says H is a cyclic subgroup, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Artin does not say **unrestricted** $H$ is cyclic.  He provides an example for the result in the previous sentence, that $H$ is in the kernel of the parity homomorphism.  The sentence under discussion is

> This will be so when $H$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by a permutation $q$ that is an element of odd order in the group.

This is an *example* of an $H$ that has odd order and is therefore subject to the conclusion of the previous sentence.

For more on the proof of the previous sentence, see [Example 2.10.3 from Artin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409117/example-2-10-3-from-artin) .

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!